# Substituting strings with sub() method with regex

Tags: python

I didn't want to write and ask this forum but I am stuck and the book I'm following, that supposed to be for beginners, is anything but...

Anyway... In the string below:

```
'Agent Alice told Agent Bob that Agent Steve was a double agent.'
```

I want to show just the first letter of the agent's first name. So what I end up with, is:

```
'Agent A**** told Agent B**** that Agent S**** was a double agent.'
```

I tried using grouping, like in the book, but its not working.

```
namesRegex = re.compile(r'\w?([A-Z])')
mo = namesRegex.sub(r'\1****', 'Agent Alice told Agent Bob that Agent 
Steve was a double agent.')
print(mo)
```

Also, I would welcome any recommended additional resources on this topic Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's not working. Do you get an error or?

Comment: i get this: ***gent ****lice told ****gent ****ob that ****gent ****teve was a double agent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use look behind `?<=` syntax for this:

```
namesRegex = re.compile(r'(?<=Agent\s[A-Z])\w+')
mo = namesRegex.sub(r'****', 'Agent Alice told Agent Bob that Agent Steve was a double agent.')

mo
# 'Agent A**** told Agent B**** that Agent S**** was a double agent.'
```

This will replace any word character `\w+` including alpha numeric characters and underscore `_` after the pattern `Agent\s[A-Z]` with `****`. If it's not guaranteed the agent's names starts with capital letter `Agent\s[A-Za-z]` would be a less restricted option.

Comment: thanks. yes that worked. So ?<= is after the pattern? That was not in the book.

Comment: You can check here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html, it is a look behind syntax which means only replace words after the pattern specified in `(?<=...)`.